# how to group in a sequence <DB2>

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table entry as below,,

```
Number  Amount  quantity
1       100     1
2       100     1
3       200     1
4       300     1
5       400     1
6       200     1
7       500     1
8       200     1
9       200     1
```

And I have a query,

```
SELECT MIN(Number), MAX(number), SUM(quantity), amount
FROM table
WHERE condition
GROUP BY number, quantity, amount.
```

This returning,

```
Start  End   quantity   amount
1      2     2          100
3      9     4          200
4      4     1          300
5      5     1          400
7      7     1          500
```

But I need result set as

```
Start  End  quantity  amount
1      2    2         100
3      3    1         200
4      4    1         300
5      5    1         400
6      6    1         200
7      7    1         500
8      9    2         200
```

** if I minus start and end then it should equal to (quantity-1)..

any help is greatly appreciated,

TIA.

Please consider this scenario as well,

```
Number  Amount  quantity
1   1000    1
2   1000    1
6   1000    1
8   1000    1
9   1000    1
```

expected result set

```
Start   End quantity    amount
1   2   2   1000
6   6   1   1000
8   9   2   1000
```

TIA

Comment: I guess the `number` was included by a typo in the first query, which should be `group by quantity,amount`

Comment: Or just `group by amount`

Comment: @ypercube I just set up a SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e71914/5/0 and just group by amount does not produce the desired result.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer I'm not talking about the desired result, I'm talking about the result shown in the question. Your fiddle (with `group by amount`) returns exactly what the OP says his query is returning (so he has something wrong).

Comment: @ypercube As far as I can see the OP only wants continuing aggregation, (thats why ids 3, 6 and 8 are seperated but 8 and 9 are combined)

Comment: @AProgrammer have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269158/oracle-sql-for-continuous-grouping Its for oracle but might work in DB2 as well.

Comment: How large are the gaps & blocks in the second scenario? Are there < 10 missing or more? (More precisely, would it be sufficient to check for the 10 numbers after start to be existent or are there larger blocks?)

Comment: thats not predictable,,but i went in the way in the url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269158/oracle-sql-for-continuous-grouping suggested by Michal Pravda.. done a small modification in that by added another case like below, `CASE
WHEN (lag(assigned_to) over(ORDER BY id) <> assigned_to OR lag(assigned_to)over(ORDER BY id) IS NULL) THEN id
WHEN ((lag(assigned_to) over(ORDER BY id) = assigned_to and LAG(id) OVER(ORDER BY id) <> id-1) OR lag(assigned_to)over(ORDER BY id) IS NULL) THEN id
                         END change_at`  it got worked. thanks a lot for ur efforts, really appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will now also cover the second scenario for situations where the adjectant blocks are only 2 elements long.

```
select min(from_id), to_id, to_id - min(from_id) +1 AS quantity, amount from
(
select from_id, max(to_id) as to_id, amount from
(
select t1.id as from_id, t2.id as to_id, t1.amount
from       foo t1
inner join foo t2 on t1.amount = t2.amount and t2.id >= t1.id
where not exists
    (
    select * from foo t3
    where  t3.ID > t1.ID
    and t3.ID < t2.ID
    and t3.amount != t1.amount
    )
  AND exists
    (
    select * from foo t3
    where ((t3.ID = t1.ID
           and t3.ID = t2.ID)
      OR (t3.ID = t1.ID +1 AND
          t3.ID = t2.ID))
    and t3.amount = t1.amount
    )
) x
group by from_id, amount
) y
group by to_id, amount
;
```

I copied the base approach from [Oracle SQL for continuous grouping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269158/oracle-sql-for-continuous-grouping) and fiddled it together here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4e0f/7/0

Comment: Hi Angelo,Thanks for your time and effort. yes it got worked but condition only when the id is in sequence.consider the case below `Number Amount quantity
1 1000 1
2 1000 1
6 1000 1
8 1000 1
9 1000 1
` for this the expected result set is `Start  End quantity amount
1 2 2 1000
6 6 1 1000
8 9 2 1000
` but its coming as `Start  End quantity amount
1 9 9 1000` but its wrong. can you help on this? thanks